# Is it bad to keep working on my computer while it is encoding music?

Tags: linux, mp3, music, encoding, file-format

I have a large amount of music that I need to convert from FLAC to mp3. It will take over a day in total. I'd like to continue working on my laptop while this is in progress. Can this cause any problems (skips in the songs, etc.)? I don't mind my laptop being slower while it's working, I just don't want to mess up the music.

If it makes a difference, I am using [Sound Converter](http://soundconverter.berlios.de/) (a music conversion tool based on GStreamer) on linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digitalizing requires how fast the audio can run in the CPU cycles. You won't get any skipping, its simply going through one second at a time and its not going to skip a second. If you keep working on the computer, you'll eat up your CPU causing the program to run a lot slower than usual.

Comment: Yup. Just don't bother trying to run any games more CPU intensive than Minesweeper :P It won't affect the encoding, but you won't get much fun out of it.

Answer (score 2):

It won't cause skipping, because it's all digital anyway. It may slow down the process though.

Answer (score 2):

It will not hurt converted files. Conversion will be a bit slower (some percent time more), but that is just a small price ;)